# "й" symbol not recognized in php scrip during RecursiveIteratorIterator of directory structure

Tags: php, encoding, cyrillic

The issue came when I've tried to find the key (filepath string from RecursiveIteratorIterator of my OSX directory tree) in array where key is a file path string and the value is some useful data.

File path strings consists of both English and Russian words, "_", "/", file extensions etc.

I've found out that php script can't recognize special Russian characters, that comes from RecursiveIteratorIterator, especially "й". Same symbol is successfully finds if I put same file path as a string directly in php code or from .json file (json_decode).

For example: 
str_replace("й","и",$file->getPath()) returns "../source/photo/Органайзеры"

And this is the key reason why I can't find those key in array, I guess.

Well, hot to fix it?
System: OSX
Php: 7.2.22

And bellow there are some tests to show the problem.

[image]

Comment: Seems fine here: https://3v4l.org/tWUi3. Are you sure `$file->getPath()` returns proper UTF8?

Comment: in phpStorm debug console echo $file->getPath() returns "../source/photo/Органайзеры". But I don't know is it proper UTF8 or not. How to check?

Comment: Go to php.net and look at the documentation of the `mb_*` functions. That said, is "recursive" really relevant? If not, [edit] your question to remove that part. Further, you say "can't recognize", but that's just your interpretation of what you saw. Much better would be to describe what you saw first. Even more, what did you actually do? Provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the faulty behaviour.